# Problem while inserting html control in my database in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is that I'm inserting HTML control using Server.HtmlEncode() method `<a href=''>Apply now!</a>` in my database through text box but whenever I'm inserting it throws an exception.

My Code is Here

```
textbox1.text=Server.Server.HtmlEncode("`<a href=''>Apply now!</a>`");

//Database entry

obj.html=textbox1.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to change

`Server.Server.HtmlEncode(`

to

`Server.HtmlEncode(`

or tell us more about what kind of exception you're getting, how do you update database etc.